# Strimzi kafka setup in GKE

Tags: r, apache-kafka, strimzi

Can anyone help to list the steps required to install Kafka with strimzi operator from scratch in GKE..

We have a confluent kafka installed on one of our VM . which we have to get rid of and install the strimzi kafka on our GKE environment from scratch., What all are the steps involved .

Gone through this document : https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/in-development/full/deploying.html

If there is any other step to step document or procedure would help .

Comment: There are no special steps for GKE. So I'm not sure what exactly are you looking for.

Comment: I am looking for a definitive steps. As i am running out of time to go through the article and perform the steps..

Comment: Not sure what is _definitive_ guide. The deployment is described in both the Quickstart guide (https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/latest/full/quickstart.html#proc-install-product-str) and Deployment guide (https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/latest/full/deploying.html#deploy-tasks_str).

Comment: @Jakub., Followed the steps provided in the document https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/in-development/quickstart.html#proc-install-product-str . when i run the command to start the my-cluster kafka cluster only zookeeper is starting up .. Dont see kafka pods., Any idea what to check and how to resolve.?

Comment: You would need to check / share the logs from the operator. Might be best done on Slack or in GitHub discussion I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very helpful guide for setting up the kafka using strimzi operator https://dzone.com/articles/grafana-and-prometheus-setup-with-strimzi-aka-kafk.

Though the quickstart guide is good. Setting up promethues and grafana is not listed there.

Comment: One important point is to NOT use GKE Autopilot at the moment. It results in the Zookeeper and Kafka being killed after 5 to 20 minutes with SIGKILL (despite having ample K8s reserved memory and tweaking JVM memory). Standard K8s clusters work, no problem.

Comment: This seems to have been solved on GKE. Autopilot no longer causes Strimzi to crash. There is even official documentation for Strimzi on Autopilot: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/apache-kafka-strimzi